# qgraphicsview horizontal scrolling always has a vertical delta

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I've subclassed QGraphicsView for a custom canvas to be used in a CAD application. I've successfully reimplemented QGraphicsView::wheelEvent to check the keyboard modifiers for the control key and, if the control key is pressed, to zoom. I'm trying to implement a horizontal scroll when the user holds shift and uses the wheel.

The problem I'm having is that the horizontal scrolling also **always** scrolls up by 0.279. Not a huge problem, but hugely annoying and it points to something else being wrong.

So, here are the questions:

1. Is this the right way to implement horizontal scrolling? If not, what is?
2. How do I eliminate this delta of 0.279?

Thanks in advance. Code and sample output below

```
void myView::zoom(int delta)
{
    double factor = pow(1.2, delta/abs(delta));
    this->scale(factor, factor);
}

void myView::scrollHorizontal(int level)
{
    QPointF center = mapToScene(viewport()->rect().center());
    qDebug() << "center: " << center.x() << ", " << center.y();
    centerOn(QPointF(center.x() - level, center.y()));
}

void myView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    //qDebug() << "delta: " << event->delta();
    if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
    {
        this->zoom(event->delta());
    }
    else if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier)
    {
        this->scrollHorizontal(event->delta());
    }
    else
        QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
}
```

sample output from the qDebug() line in scrollHorizontal when at the left-edge of the scene:

```
center:  261.5 ,  615.654 
center:  261.5 ,  615.375 
center:  261.5 ,  615.096 
center:  261.5 ,  614.817 
center:  261.5 ,  614.538 
center:  261.5 ,  614.259 
center:  261.5 ,  613.98 
center:  261.5 ,  613.701 
center:  261.5 ,  613.421
```

Comment: That is weird.  I do find the `QGraphicsView` scrolling a little 'unnatural' when you reach the bounds of the scene rectangle, is the behaviour the same regardless of where the visible rect is in the scene rect?

Comment: While it'd be interesting to know what is causing the issue, what you're doing is quite bad from the [UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com) perspective. If someone wants a horizontal scroll, they can simply use an input device that has it implemented. Like all recent trackpads, mice with scroll paddles or multitouch, etc. Presumably, a CAD user can afford a decent input device and you don't need to offer such workarounds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that `mapToScene()` processes an integer point, not a floating point point. The rounding error is always pointed the same way for a particular viewport size, thus you always add some delta.

You want to be directly modifying the scroll bar's `value` property or sending the event to the horizontal scroll bar. I've implemented the latter, it's simple enough.

On a Mac, you must absolutely disable the scrollbar inertia for your application. Otherwise as soon as you release the modifier and lift your finger off the trackpad/scroll wheel, vertical scrolling will continue due to inertia. This would make Mac users' experience suck and they would hate you for it :)

[image: screenshot]

`gview-scroll.pro`

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = gview-scroll
TEMPLATE = app
macx {
    LIBS += -framework Foundation
    OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += helper.m
}
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

`helper.m`

```
//helper.m
#include <Foundation/NSUserDefaults.h>
#include <Foundation/NSDictionary.h>
#include <Foundation/NSString.h>

void disableMomentumScroll(void)
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"NO" forKey:@"AppleMomentumScrollSupported"];
    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QtCore/qmath.h>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <QDebug>

class View : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    void zoom(int delta) {
        double factor = qPow(1.2, delta/qAbs(delta));
        scale(factor, factor);
    }
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) {
        if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) {
            zoom(event->delta());
        }
        else if (event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier) {
            horizontalScrollBar()->event(event);
        }
        else {
            QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);
        }
    }
public:
    explicit View(QWidget *parent=0) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}
    explicit View(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent=0) : QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {}
};

#ifndef Q_OS_MAC
void disableMomentumScroll() {}
#else
extern "C" { void disableMomentumScroll(); }
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    disableMomentumScroll();
    QGraphicsScene s;
    s.addEllipse(-50, -50, 100, 100, QPen(Qt::red), QBrush(Qt::gray));
    View w(&s);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```